# Matlab sort and get ranking of the oringal matrix

Tags: matlab

Please help me find an efficient way **(no for loop)** to get the ranking for a matrix.

**Example:**

```
orig_matrix = [-1 2 nan 2 3 4 -2; 100 nan nan -100 300 1000 0]';
[matrix_sorted, id] = sort(orig_matrix ,1,'ascend');
```

I know 'id' is the location of the elements of  matrix_sorted in the orig_matrix. But I want to get the ranking of all elements in orig_matrix, something like this:

```
ranking = [2 3 7 4 5 6 1; 3 6 7 1 4 5 2]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: How are you deciding the rank of ties (like where you have 2 equal elements)? You wan the rankings just within each column?

Comment: Have a look at this [post on Matlab forum](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/21/reversal-of-a-sort/#7), should answer your problem.

Comment: I can't figure out how you want to rank them, based on your example.

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding to OmG's post, you can also specify which dimension to sort individually so you don't need to transpose:

```
[B, Result] = sort(orig_matrix, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by a simple trick using transposing:

```
[B, I] = sort(orig_matrix.');
Result = I.';
```

Comment: You can also specify which dimension to sort individually so you don't need to transpose: `[B, I] = sort(orig_matrix, 2);`.